# Integrating Twitter like IOS - 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, twitter

i want to integrate twitter like IOS- 5 in my app. like IOS-5 i want to tweet images from my app. is there any library for this ?

Comment: Start reading [this](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios)

Comment: Did you try to google for it? There are many tutorials already. And you can always start by reading the documents for the Twitter.framework

Comment: i am talking about integrate twitter like IOS-5 ,exact like it.

Comment: is there any sample code or library for this ?

Comment: I am talking about the same thing as well!

Comment: is there any sample code or library for this ?

Comment: You really need to explain better what you want to do. Is it communication with Twitter's API, or do you want to use the new feature of iOS 5 to send tweets from within your app?

Comment: yes i want the new feature of iOS 5 to send tweets from within my app and i want to tweet images too like photos app in ios 5.

Comment: The link that devXcode gave you is a perfect place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi i got sample code for this http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Tweeting/Introduction/Intro.html here.

in this code inside - (IBAction)sendEasyTweet:(id)sender {
    [tweetViewController addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon.png"]];

}

you can send image too.thanks devXcode and Irene for your help

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try ShareKit, http://getsharekit.com/.

If you just want to integrate twitter, you can follow https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios.

If you just want to support iOS 5, there is built in twitter integration in iOS 5.